# SharePoint 2013: Drag and drop not working in model dialog

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, modal-dialog

Scenario: I have external users and i am opening a SharePoint document library in model dialog. It works perfectly if users clicks on "New document" link and add documents. But if they try to drag and drop documents, it doesnt work. SharePoint seems to be busy (shown in image below) in uploading documents, but it never got finished.

[image]

Does any one having same issue or know solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

could you please attach the screenshot of your document library model dialog, how it looks like? Normally there is no drag and drop feature in the dialog box through Upload Documents option. There is only way to choose the document location.

What kind of Browser are the users using?
As my experiences, the drag and drop feature is available after IE9. However if you have SharePoint Designer Application in your machine, it will work with IE9.

Please let me know if it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer myself. The solution is to deactivate feature called "Limited-access user permissions lockdown mode". Here is article about how to do it.

[SharePoint 2013 and anonymous users accessing lists and libraries](http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2013/01/26/sharepoint-2013-and-anonymous-users-accessing-lists-and-libraries.aspx)